# How do I play an animation in a specific place controlled by actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have this moving character and when I press a button I want it to shoot at a object pointed by the mouse. But the character is moving so I don't know how to make the animation in a specific place. I am using Flash, actionscript 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in which it can be done, but this one is known to be one of the simplest:

Given source point A and target point B:

Calculate distance between A and B

```
var distance:Number = computeDistance(A,B); //define your function where computeDistance returns the Pythagorean distance between A and B
```

Calculate x and y difference

```
var dx:Number = B.x - A.x;
var dy:Number = B.y - A.y;    

// normalization. Think of this as a ratio of the legs relative to the hypotenuse
dx = dx / distance; 
dy = dy / distance;`
```

Calcualate xSpeed and ySpeed by multiplying `dx` and `dy` with `speedPerFrame` (arbitrary)

```
var xSpeed:Number = dx*speedPerFrame;
var ySpeed:Number = dy*speedPerFrame;
```

Increment your object's `x` and `y` position using `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` in the main game loop (respectively). Make sure you add a check if the object has arrived at the destination point.